# Integrate $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{(5-3\sin(t))^2}dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I have to compute the following integral: 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{(5-3\sin(t))^2}dt$$

Let $z= e^{it}$, then we write the integral als an integral over the unit circle $|z|=1$.

$$\int_{|z|=1}\frac1{\left(5-3\left[\frac1{2i}\left(z-\frac1z\right)\right]\right)^2}\frac{1}{iz}dz=$$ 
$$-i\int_{|z|=1}\frac z{\left(5z-\frac3{2i}+\frac3{2i}z^2\right)^2}dz=$$ 
$$-4i\int_{|z|=1}\frac z{(z+3i)^2\left(z+\frac13i\right)^2} dz=$$ 
$$-4i*2\pi i*\text{Res}\left(f,-\frac i3\right)$$

Since $-3i$ lies outside the unit circle. Also, $-\frac i3$ is a pole of order $2$ and $f(z)=\frac z{(z+3i)^2\left(z+\frac13i\right)^2}$.

I calculated the residue, and found:

$$\text{Res}\left(f,-\frac i3\right) = 
\left[\frac z{(z+3i)^2}\right]'_{z=-\frac i3} 
=\left[\frac{-z + 3i}{(z + 3i)^2}\right]_{z=-\frac i3}
=\frac{\frac i3 + 3i}{\left(-\frac i3 + 3i\right)^2} 
=-\frac{45}{256}$$

So the end answer would be:

$$-4i*2\pi i*-\frac{45}{256}=\frac{45\pi}{32}$$

However, this is not the correct answer. The right answer is namely $\frac{5 \pi}{32}$. I do not really see where I made the mistake, so if anyone could give me a helping hand, that would be really nice!

Comment: See this related post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2874730/use-contour-integral-to-show-int-02-pi-frac-mathrm-dt1-cosu-cost/.  Although you have $\sin$ in your integral, the answer will be the same if you replace $\sin$ by $\cos$ and use the result from the link.  That is, $$\int_0^{2\pi}\,\frac{1}{\big(5-3\,\sin(t)\big)^2}\,\text{d}t=\int_0^{2\pi}\,\frac{1}{\big(5-3\,\cos(t)\big)^2}\,\text{d}t=\frac{1}{25}\,\left(\frac{2\pi}{\left(1-\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2\right)^{\frac32}}\right)\,.$$  Thus, the final result is indeed $\dfrac{5\pi}{32}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(5-3sin(t))^2} dt=\oint _{|z|=1}\frac{1}{\left(5-3\frac{z^2-1}{2iz}\right)^2}\frac{dz}{iz}$$ Now here its a small mistake, note that when you get to the same denominator you should have:
$$\begin{align*}I &=\oint _{|z|=1}\frac{(2iz)^2}{\left(10iz-3(z^2-1)\right)^2}\frac{dz}{iz}\\ &=4i\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z}{(3z^2-10iz-3)^2}dz\end{align*}$$
Now here you did another small mistake $$(3z^2-10iz-3)^2=9(z-3i)^2(z-i/3)^2$$ The next step is like yours. $$I=\frac{4i}{9}2\pi i \text{Res}(f,\frac{i}{3})=-\frac{8\pi}{9}\left(\frac{z}{(z-3i)^2}\right)'_{z=\frac{i}{3}}=\frac{8\pi}{9}\frac{i/3+3i}{(i/3-3i)^3}= \frac{8\pi}{9}\frac{45}{256}=\frac{5\pi}{32}$$